# How do I find the number of hash calculation required to reverse a hash?

Tags: hash

Let *x* be an arbitrary 256-bit value. The output of *H(x)* is smaller than 2^215. How many hash functions do I have to compute to find a solution?

I have tried to solve this problem with a pre-image attack. 
And the result came that if the output of the hash is less than 2^215 then we need to compute the hash 2^215 times. Is that correct?

Comment: I'm not familiar with cryptography from an academic perspective but from a practical perspective I'm fairly certain your only option is to brute force it. You can't know how many times the hash function has been composited because it's just the output of the previous function thrown back into itself many times.

Answer (score 1):

A good hash function trying distinct new inputs will uniformly sample the output space with 2<sup>256</sup> possible outputs.  Now for the output to be less than 2<sup>215</sup> there are exactly 2<sup>215</sup> potential output values (from 0 to 2<sup>215</sup>-1) that satisfy it.  So the probability of getting an output in this range by trying one hash is p₁ = 2<sup>215</sup>/2<sup>256</sup> = 2<sup>-41</sup>.

Now if you try this twice (e.g., hash two distinct random inputs), the chance of at least one output being in range is `p₂ = 1 - (1-p₁)*(1-p₁)`, as `(1-p₁)` is the probability of the first hash not being in less than 2<sup>215</sup>, `(1-p₁)(1-p₁)` is the probability of both the first and second hash not being less than 2<sup>215</sup>, and then we take the complement of that probability (to ensure that either the first hash or the second hash is in the range).  Similarly, if you did hashed three random inputs, the chance of at least one output being in range is `p₃ = 1 - (1-p₁)*(1-p₁)*(1-p₁)`; that is unless all three are simultaneously not in the range, then at least one of them is in range.  As you can see, this generalizes for hashing N separate hashes to be `p(N) = 1 - (1-p₁)^N`.

If you want to have say a 99% chance of a solution, you set `p(N) = .99 = 1 - (1-p₁)^N` and solve for N, which rearranging becomes `(1-p₁)^N = .01`, then taking the natural log of both sides and using properties of logs becomes:

`N = (ln .01)/(ln [1 - p₁]) = 10126876334760.2 ~ 1.01 x 10^13`

Note, you can use the Taylor series approximation that `ln (1 - x) ~ -x` when x is small (e.g., in our example when it is `2^-41`)in the above equation to simplify it to `N = ln (1/100) / (-p₁) = 2<sup>41</sup> ln 100` if you want to evaluate it analytically.